# C++11 range-based for() loops evaluate once or multiple times?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, foreach

Given this C++11 example code:

```
for ( const auto &foo : bar() )
{
    // ... do something with foo...
}
```

Is it **guaranteed** by the standard that the expression `bar()` in this example is evaluated only once?

Or could it end up being called at every iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is evaluated only once. The standard says that the range-based for loop is equivalent to this:

<sub>§6.5.4 *The range-based for statement* [stmt.ranged]</sub>

```
{
  auto && __range = range-init;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
        __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

with `range-init` being equivalent to `( bar() )` in your case (the expression you specify, surrounded by parenthesis). That expression is only evaluated once as you can see.