# Is the expression in a ranged-for statement evaluated on each iteration?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I do:

```
for (auto p : foo()) {
   // ...
}
```

is `foo()` evaluated on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Oh, oops...... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259574/c11-range-based-for-loops-evaluate-once-or-multiple-times?rq=1 :( That didn't show up in the "related posts" list while composing this, at all. Grr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, only once.**

> `[C++11: 6.5.4]:` For a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
> ```
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the expression surrounded by parentheses
>
> ```
> ( expression )
> ```
>
> *[..]* a range-based for statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>    auto && __range = range-init;
>    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>               __end = end-expr;
>         __begin != __end;
>         ++__begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>       statement
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> *[..]*

Interestingly, this relatively new passage is a rare example of the standard defining semantics in terms of code using pre-existing language features. I guess they got bored of writing terse technical language.

It means we have to *deduce* the fact above from the code; in this case, fortunately, it's easy: *range-init* is evaluated once and bound to the universal reference `__range`.

Comment: *"pre-existing language features"* should be *"other existing language features"*, as `auto &&` didn't exist before in the language. +1, though.

Comment: @Nawaz: Well, fair enough. I meant the non-ranged-`for`, though ;)